# how to update the related data in database table if someone changed data in admin page

Tags: django

I have a table named project,the table has the following columns:
"id,name,prodid,unitid,starttime,endtime", the value of "name" is combined with the name of "prodid" and "unitid", prodid and unitid are foreign key here.

IF someone changed the name of the projid and unitid in admin page, how to update the "name" column for the related row in this table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use django [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)